Unclear Load Switch Operation
I've check the datasheets for these components even ran a simulation which verifies that the circuit works, but it's still somehow not obvious to me how.



Original image link: Hackaday - Lithium-Ion Battery Circuitry Is Simple by Arya Voronova
BATT+ is just around 3.5V nominally. when the +5V input is removed i.e. the charging cable is unplugged, the gate voltage = 0V => VGS = 0V. Theoretically, this should be able to turn on some mosfets and make VSW == BATT+ but practically this isn't so according to the VGS threshold values given by basically every datasheet; VGS threshold is usually negative.
Also when the charging cable is attached (+5V like in the diagram). The voltage drop across D1 should be around 0.5V or so. Meaning that VS = +4.5V and VG = +5V. VSW also = +4.5V. Since VGS = +0.5V the FET would remain closed and the battery wouldn't be used. A good explanation of how the load switches to BATT+ would be appreciated, considering the above paragraph.

I recommend using a simulator to show prevailing conditions:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
VM1 shows \$V_{SG}=V_S-V_G\$, which must be strongly positive for a P-channel MOSFET to be switched on. It's worth noting that if I flipped VM1 upside down, then it would measure \$V_{GS}=V_G-V_S\$ instead, and we would require a strongly negative reading to indicate that the MOSFET was on.
In the above situation, where the 5V source is absent, gate potential is held at \$V_G=0V\$ by R1. The body diode of M1 is conducting, guaranteeing that \$V_S>V_{BAT}-0.7V\$. Consequently \$V_{SG}\$ is very positive (or \$V_{GS}\$ is very negative), and the MOSFET is definitely on.
Interestingly, since M1 is now on, it effectively short-circuits its own body diode, raising \$V_S\$ even further, even closer to \$V_{BAT}\$. Initially, then, it's the body-diode that raises \$V_S\$, followed very quickly by the MOSFET's channel switching on and reinforcing its own on-state.
Now I add the 5V source, causing gate potential \$V_G\$ to rise:

simulate this circuit
Now \$V_G > V_S\$, so \$V_{SG}\$ has become slightly negative, and the MOSFET is off. The body-diode stops conducting because now \$V_S > V_{BAT}\$, and the only path for current to the load is via D1. You see output \$V_{SW}\$ a little under 5V due to D1's forward voltage.

this is really helpful Simon. Thanks!

As you show, it is a P-channel. It works as you correctly states by having a negative Vgs. That is exactly what happens when the gate is pulled to GND by R1. Then the gate is 0V and the Sourse is +Batt. So Vgs is equal to -(+Batt).
Initially it will the battery will use the body diode to turn on the P-channel.
You are correct about the diode. It will feed the circuit and disable the P-channel.

isnt the mosfet supposed to have a high impedance before being turned on? which makes current flowing through the body diode impossible?

@Cambio You can't disable the body diode. It's always there and you can't contro it.

Edit: I was conflating reverse polarity protection operation with ideal diode controller operation.
In this application, the P-channel MOSFET is connected "backwards" with source and drain switched. This is to prevent the body diode from allowing reverse current flow from the 5V supply to the battery. Since MOSFETs are mostly symmetrical devices, in the absence of the 5V supply, the drain (acting as the source) voltage is high enough relative to the gate to enhance a channel and allow current flow.
When the 5V supply is connected, Vgs is slightly positive and the transistor remains "off". The body diode is blocking in this case.
The body diode is an integral part of the transistor and acts just like a normal diode connected between source and drain. Most datasheets will give specifications for the body diode separate section.

isnt the mosfet supposed to have a high impedance before being turned on? which makes current flowing through the body diode impossible?

The body diode will always conduct if biased correctly; in this case if Vd > Vs. This is why the MOSFET is "backwards" compared to a normal high side switching configuration. See my edit above for more.

this might be the missing piece. never considered that the body diode always conducts
